# Find intersection of two tetrahedral using point test

Tags: matlab, geometry, computational-geometry, tetrahedra

I'm new to Matlab programming. I have two models created by tetrahedral meshes by using EIDORS and Netgen. Then i need to create a map based on the intersection between the tetrahedral elements by using Matlab. So, in order to find the intersection i tried using the point test method. Please refer to the link.
**http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/geometry/ptintet.html**

Let's assume model1 and model2.

First, i extract the vertices from both models and created matrices.

Then, i used the point test method to calculate the intersection between the models.

For model1 i have 3000++ tetrahedral elements and model2 i have 8000++ tetrahedral elements.

In order to calculate the intersection, i looped one by one to determine which of the elements between the two models have intersection and then i created a matrix by indexing the element number of model2 to the element number of model1.

But, there appears to be zero for few elements which is not possible because all elements from model1 should atleast intersects with a few of the elements from model2.

Therefore, in the end i expect to get a matrix consists of (the element number of model1 x the element number of model2 which intersects with the corresponding elements from model1). Can help me solve this? Please refer to my code.

```
function [elemno,deter0,deter1,deter2,deter3,deter4] = checkp(filename1,filename2);

%/* to check whether the vertices of a layered model''s element are inside the
% tetrahedron of the generic model
%after the model is created using netgen and eidors, there will be a struct    type 
%named model_parameters.
%model_parameters.vtx refers to the vertices which consists of (nodes x   vertices %(x,y,z))
%model_parameters.simp refers to the elements which consists (numberofelements x nodes) nodes are linked to the vertices.*/

filename1 = [filename1 '.mat'];
filename2 =[filename2 '.mat'];

first = load(filename1);
second =load(filename2);

vtx = first.model_parameters.vtx;
simp = first.model_parameters.simp;
[simpr,simpc] = size(simp);

vtx2 = second.model_parameters.vtx;
simp2= second.model_parameters.simp;
[simpr2,simpc2] = size(simp2);


%//extracting the vertices of the elements from the simplices(element)
for loop1 = 1 : simpr
    elemx(loop1,1) = vtx(simp(loop1,1),1);      
    elemx(loop1,2) = vtx(simp(loop1,2),1);
    elemx(loop1,3) = vtx(simp(loop1,3),1);
    elemx(loop1,4) = vtx(simp(loop1,4),1);

    elemy(loop1,1) = vtx(simp(loop1,1),2);
    elemy(loop1,2) = vtx(simp(loop1,2),2);
    elemy(loop1,3) = vtx(simp(loop1,3),2);
    elemy(loop1,4) = vtx(simp(loop1,4),2);

    elemz(loop1,1) = vtx(simp(loop1,1),3);
    elemz(loop1,2) = vtx(simp(loop1,2),3);
    elemz(loop1,3) = vtx(simp(loop1,3),3);
    elemz(loop1,4) = vtx(simp(loop1,4),3);

end

for loop2 = 1:simpr2
    elemx2(loop2,1) = vtx2(simp2(loop2,1),1);
    elemx2(loop2,2) = vtx2(simp2(loop2,2),1);
    elemx2(loop2,3) = vtx2(simp2(loop2,3),1);
    elemx2(loop2,4) = vtx2(simp2(loop2,4),1);

    elemy2(loop2,1) = vtx2(simp2(loop2,1),2);
    elemy2(loop2,2) = vtx2(simp2(loop2,2),2);
    elemy2(loop2,3) = vtx2(simp2(loop2,3),2);
    elemy2(loop2,4) = vtx2(simp2(loop2,4),2);

    elemz2(loop2,1) = vtx2(simp2(loop2,1),3);
    elemz2(loop2,2) = vtx2(simp2(loop2,2),3);
    elemz2(loop2,3) = vtx2(simp2(loop2,3),3);
    elemz2(loop2,4) = vtx2(simp2(loop2,4),3);

end
%//point test calculation
r =[1;1;1;1];
for a = 1:simpr
    m=1;
    for b=1:simpr2  
        for n = 1:4
            p = [elemx2(b,n),elemy2(b,n),elemz2(b,n)];
            n1=[elemx(a,1),elemy(a,1),elemz(a,1)];
            n2=[elemx(a,2),elemy(a,2),elemz(a,2)];
            n3=[elemx(a,3),elemy(a,3),elemz(a,3)];
            n4=[elemx(a,4),elemy(a,4),elemz(a,4)];
            d0 =[n1;n2;n3;n4];
            d0 =[d0 r];
            d1 =[p;n2;n3;n4];
            d1 =[d1 r];
            d2 =[n1;p;n3;n4];
            d2 =[d2 r];
            d3 =[n1;n2;p;n4];
            d3 =[d3 r];
            d4 =[n1;n2;n3;p];
            d4 =[d4 r];
            deter0 = sign(det(d0));
            deter1 = sign(det(d1));
            deter2 = sign(det(d2));
            deter3 = sign(det(d3));
            deter4 = sign(det(d4));
            if isequal(deter0,deter1,deter2,deter3,deter4)
                elemno(a,m) = b;   
                m=m+1;
                break;
            else
                continue;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that all vertices of two tetrahedrons could lie outside each other, but these tetrahedrons do intersect, so point test **is not reliable method**.

Possible robust and fast approach is the [method of separating axes](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/MethodOfSeparatingAxes.pdf).

I've used 2D version for quick selection of intersecting pairs between two sets containing a lot of (10^4 and 10^6) convex polygons, but 3D version also looks simple enough.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understand what you have mentioned that the point test is not reliable. However, I don't think I really understand about the direction D in the method which u have posted. And I'm dealing with meshes i'm not sure i have the direction D for all of the tetrahedral elementes.

Comment: I don't know about meshes structure. But for this method one has to use properly ordered vertices for each face  - to know, what side(normal) is outward. It is not hard to determine right orientation for tetrahedron - it is enough to get some inner point M (for example, mean of all vertices), and check the sign of scalar product of normal and MX vector, where X is any vertice for given face. If sign is negative, just inverse normal.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with geometry. If it is possible, can you please show me an example of applying the method of separating axes? I'm having a really hard time understanding the pseudocode. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience in 3D case, and don't know matlab. Eberly, author of that article, maintains C++ library, containing needed data structures and code, if it could help you: http://www.geometrictools.com/Downloads/Downloads.html

Comment: It's okay. At least i learned something new. I will try to understand the separate axes method to see if i can put it to good use. Thank you very much.